# Elasticsearch: Find one document from wildcard search of indices

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch database contains hundreds of indices starting with a word like 'myindex' (indices would be myindex_1, myindex_2 etc).  All these indices contain the same named doc_type, eg 'mydoctype'.

These doc_types have multiple documents.  Among other fields, each document has an id field called myid with unique numbers.

I want to get a list of documents - one document from each index with the criteria that that document has the lowest myid number.

I used to do this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://<es_host>/myindex*/mydoctype/_search?_source_include=duration&from=0&size=10000&pretty'
```

But this generates a big list of all the documents from each index's mydoctype.

So, I tried to do this based on some examples I saw here on SO:

```
curl -XGET 'http://<es_host>/myindex*/mydoctype/_search?_source_include=duration&from=0&size=10000&pretty' -d '
    {
        "sort": [
            {"myid": "asc"}
        ]
    }
'
```

The above just sorts it and with the size being 10000, and still lists all the documents.  Changing size to 1, just returns with exactly 1 document.

I am looking to have a list of documents, 1 document from each index's doctype, where their document has the lowest myid value in that index's doctype.

Is there some query I can use to get this?  I tried do the search by looping through each index individually and then getting the document with the lowest myid, but this kind of search takes way longer to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `terms` aggregation on the `_index` field and then use `top_hits` to return only that one document with the lowest `myid` value, like this:

```
POST /myindex*/mydoctype/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "indexes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index", 
        "size": 500
      },
      "aggs": {
        "lowest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": ["myid", "duration"],
            "sort": {
              "myid": "asc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is way further than I could take it.  However, it is only returning 10 results, whereas I was expecting a few hundred due to the number of indexes.  Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I've added the `size` parameter to the `terms` aggregation. Feel free to adjust it as you see fit.